# VS Code Typescript: expand type tooltips

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've been trying for way too long to get the VSC tooltip to show me a function's parameters' properties:

Hovering over an Interface gave me nothing:

[image: Tooltip from hovering over an Interface]

Hovering over a Type worked, which was exciting and also weird because the Interface doesn't recursively expand:

[image: Tooltip from hovering over a Type]

Unfortunately, hovering over a function doesn't expand its params:

[image: Tooltip from creating a function]

Am I missing something? It'd be incredible if I could see a parameter's shape or Type doc without having to go to the function's file/d.ts, and then to the param's type file.

Example with an inferred type:

[image: inferred type tooltip]

Or this beauty VS Code gives you while typing:

[image: typing helper tooltip]

Did just discover the "Add Missing Properties" which looks amazingly helpful:

[image: Add Missing Properties Tooltip]
[image: Added Properties from "Add Missing Properties"]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Recursive introspection is kind of a sore spot in TS. However, you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on a type name to go to the place where it's defined (or view a list of references if there are multiple).

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's how I've been navigating to the function's file so far, but then I have to navigate to the type if it's a in different file.  Then if there's a union it gets even more complicated.  Getting a quick expanded view of all the primitives, even just one level down would be so helpful.

Comment: I’ve noticed that by using type aliases (defined using the `type` keyword) instead of interfaces, TS seems to be more willing to show me expanded primitives on cmd/ctrl + hover/click. I haven’t yet taken time to investigate why that is.